# How to shoot a bullet at an angle in pygame?

Tags: python, math, pygame, bulletphysics, bullet

I am making a game in pygame, and when you shoot a bullet, the bullet travels in the same direction that your mouse is. Here is my code for my `Player` class:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.game = game
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, game.all_sprites)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
        self.image.fill(settings.player_color)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = x, y
        self.pos = Vector2(x, y)

        self.speed = Vector2(0, 0)

        self.is_shooting = False

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.speed
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = self.pos.x, self.pos.y

    def shoot(self):
        self.is_shooting = True
        m_x, m_y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        b_m_x, b_m_y = m_x - self.pos.x, m_y - self.pos.y
        b = Bullet(self.game, self.rect.x - 50, self.rect.y - 50 / 2, b_m_x, b_m_y)
        _, angle = (pygame.mouse.get_pos() - self.pos).as_polar()
        b.rotate(_)
```

The way I am making the bullet path is I am making it so that the bullet has a slope just like a line. `b_m_x` and `b_m_y` is the change in `x` and the change in `y`.

I am only just starting to learn algebra this year (I am 13), and I learned how to graph linear lines last year, so if there is an easier way to make the bullet path, please let me know.

Here is my code for my Bullet Class

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, x, y, run, rise):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, game.all_sprites)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((15, 50))
        self.image.fill((255, 0, 0))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = x, y
        self.pos = pygame.math.Vector2(self.rect.x, self.rect.y)
        self.speed = pygame.math.Vector2(x=run / settings.bullet_speed_offset, y=rise / settings.bullet_speed_offset)

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.speed
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = self.pos.x, self.pos.y

    def rotate(self, angle):
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.image, angle, 1)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

My problem is that the farther my mouse is away from the `Player` sprite, the faster the bullet travels (because when I find the slope of the line, the bigger the difference is between the mouse and the player, the faster the speed of the bullet will be). How can I make a better system of firing bullets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should normalize the distance to the mouse if you want the speed not to depend on the mouse distance.

In other words, regardless of where the mouse is, use the coordinates of the point which is in that same direction, but at a fixed distance from the starting position, e.g. when you calculate your `b_m_x`and `b_m_y`, do this:

```
b_m_x, b_m_y = m_x - self.pos.x, m_y - self.pos.y

distance = (b_m_x ** 2 + b_m_y ** 2) ** .5

if distance != 0:
    # if distance is 0, nothing can be done

    NORMALIZED_DISTANCE = 100
    mutiplier = NORMALIZED_DISTANCE / distance

    b_m_x *= multipler
    b_m_y *= multipler
```

Comment: This worked, but the only time where my problem still occurs is when the mouse is below the player

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it by making distance = (b_m_x ** 2 + b_m_y ** 2) ** .5 instead of distance = (b_m_x ** 2 + b_m_x ** 2) ** .5. I changed the second b_m_x to b_m_y

Comment: @Shaan Yes, that was my mistake.